# Change Pandas DataFrame column values from array to first value in array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a `labels` column. The `labels` column is currently an array, and I would like to map the entire column to the first item of the array for each row without naively iterating.

For example, if I have 2 rows with `labels` values ['1','m'], ['0'], I would like to map the current values to the new values '1','0'.

Comment: `df.labels = df.labels.apply(lambda x: x[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str` for this:

```
df['labels'] = df['labels'].str[0]
```

However, it (and other possible ways) is essentially just a loop:

```
df['labels'] = [x[0] for x in df['labels'] ]
```

I'd recommend doing a loop since you have better control of error handling, e.g.:

```
# this handles empty array as well as NaN values
df['labels'] = [x[0] if x else np.nan for x in df['labels']]
```